# Datagridview data binding from database error

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005-express

I have a datagridview in my Windows C# application. I am binding some data from my SQL server 2005 database into it.
The datagridview already has a fixed number of columns and rows with their indivdual names.
The problem is the data is displayed after the columns where i wish to get my data. The code is as following

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from INV_details_1 where i_n = '" + textBox3.Text + "'", sconn);

            SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter();

            da2.SelectCommand = cmd;

            DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();

           da2.Fill(ds2);

            dgv_details.DataSource = ds2.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

The issue is that the data is getting displayed after my desired column headers. I wish to get the data in these specified columns.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must map each column of the datagridview with the corresponding column in database using `DataPropertyName` property of Datagridview's column. EX:

```
dgv_details.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "Name"
```

This will map column 0 in datagridview with column "Name" in datatable